# Passing parameter into an OLE DB component using parameters not variables SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, business-intelligence

I'm having difficulty passing a parameter into stored procedure in my SSIS OLE DB Source. I keep getting

```
[Get ************ [2]] Error: The SQL command requires a parameter named "@numberOfRecords", which is not found in the parameter mapping.]
```

sp looks like this:

`EXECUTE usp_get_encrypted_value_without_nums @numberOfRecords ?` --This didn't work

`EXECUTE usp_get_encrypted_value_without_nums ?` --This also didn't work

This parameter has been declared and assigned a value in my parameter.
I will real appreciate if its a case of mis-mapping or if parameters can't be used to set values into an sp.

Flow diagram:
[image: Flow Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
EXECUTE usp_get_encrypted_value_without_nums ?
```

In the parameter mappings, map parameter `0` to the value you want to pass.

Comment: I discovered that the problem was the parameter name was not same as what was in my sp ie. 

    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_get_encrypted_value_without_nums]
    (
     @numberOfRecords BIGINT
      )
     AS
     BEGIN

this link helped: 
http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2009/03/05/mapping-stored-procedure-parameters-in-ssis-ole-db-source-editor.aspx

[Parameter Mapping][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YIAto.jpg